# Book about three teenaged sisters who each possess some sort of magical gift

Tags: story-identification, books

I am trying to find a book, there's 3 magical sisters, one red head, one with black hair and one blonde. I think they may have been teenagers and orphans, and each had some sort of magical gift. It was set in modern day and I would have read them sometime between 2000-2005.

I have tried searching Google and at my local library but can't seem to find it.

Comment: Karmas Witches? The books are written by 3 different authors. The girls are named Topaz, Amber and Amethyst.https://www.fantasticfiction.com/r/elizabeth-a-reeves/karmas-witches/

Comment: I think those are the books - thank you so much!

Comment: @sueelleker - You should write that up as an answer so that OP can accept it :-)

Comment: The parallelism with Hocus Pocus is uncanny

Answer (score 3):

*[Karmas Witches](http://fantasticfiction.com/r/elizabeth-a-reeves/karmas-witches)*. The books are written by 3 different authors. The girls are named Topaz, Amber and Amethyst.